# How can I create a symbolic link of a file in another directory with relative path?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, docker, symbolic-link

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm developping an ai training app. The app uses docker and some folders are shared (mounted). Absolute paths inside and outside docker differ, and I need to create symlinks that work on both.

**PATHS**

app `/opt/shared/app`

host: `/opt/<client>/app/ai/training/<uuid>/models`

docker `/workspace/tlt-experiments/training/<uuid>/models`

**DESCRIPTION**

When I execute a training program (inside docker) it will generate in the directory files
called `model.epoch0.tlt, model.epoch1.tlt, ... model.epoch<n>.tlt`

If I `cd` into host dir or docker dir and execute `ln -s model.epoch<n>.tlt model.tlt`, I have a link that's valid inside the docker container and in the host machine

But if I execute from the app a command to generate the links, I need to use absolute routing
`ln -s /opt/<client>/app/ai/training/<uuid>/models/model.epoch<n>.tlt /opt/<client>/app/ai/training/<uuid>/models/model.tlt`, which works for the host but is an invalid link pointing to nothing if I execute anything inside the container.

Is there an elegant way to create the link (hopefully not using `cd-ln-cd`)?

**BONUS**

The command I currently use to create the link is the following. It helps me get the last epoch (n)

```
ls -t <host>/models/ | head -1 | xargs -I @ ln -s <host>/models/@ <host>/models/model.tlt
```

**ADITIONAL INFO**

This part of the app's code is written in c, but for the links I'm executing unix commands as parsed strings on system(str) calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I `cd` into host dir or docker dir and execute `ln -s model.epoch<n>.tlt model.tlt`, I have a link that's valid inside the docker container and in the host machine

The link target has no relationship to the current directory. Specifying a relative path as the target will always store that *exact* path in the link, whether you do it after `cd`-ing somewhere or not.

So you can literally use:

```
ln -s model.epoch<n>.tlt /opt/<client>/app/ai/training/<uuid>/models/model.tlt
```

Newer GNU Coreutils versions also add an `-r` option to automatically transform absolute paths into relative ones.

Comment: Thank you, the -r did the trick!

Comment: You slightly missed the point of my post, I think – _you can still do this without `-r`,_ though it does make things easier.

Comment: I didn't miss it, I appreciate the input and your answer did help me to better understand the ln command, yet I needed the trick done and that little additional input on your answer help me do the trick smoothly :D, I was under a lot of pression so my first comment was on what actually solved the problem. Thank you very much!